# Probabilities of members leaving a team

Tags: probability

I have a list of teams consisting of a captain and $t$ players (not including the captain). The minimum size for a team is $m$, otherwise it cannot compete.
I suppose that $p_0$ is the probability that any one player (excluding the team captain) leaves the team for whatever reasons.

Initially all teams have at least $m$ members including the captain.
I want to calculate the probability that a team falls below the threshold $m$, due to members leaving it. Captains never leave their team.

With my limit memories of stochastics I came up with the following:

$$
p = \sum_{n=t-m+2}^{t} \binom{t}{n}p_0^n(1-p_0)^{t-n}
$$

The idea behind this is: How many combinations of n players leaving are there. Multiply it with the probability that exactly n players leave. Sum everything up.

**Does this make any sense?**

**If it does make sense, can the expression be simplified?**

Comment: It makes sense. You could also ask for the probability that at less than $m-1$ of
the $t$ players 'stays'. Denoting this probability that a fixed player
stays by $q_{0}$ you come to:

$p=\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\binom{t}{n}q_{0}^{n}\left(1-q_{0}\right)^{t-n}$.
Note that here $p_{0}+q_{0}=1$ so you can also write $p=\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\binom{t}{n}q_{0}^{n}p_{0}^{t-n}$. That is (a bit) simpler in my view, but not in an essential way.

Comment: @drhab Thank you very much. Well done, good and faithful servant!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming different players' leaving are independent events (a doubtful assumption in reality, as it would be spoiled by personal relations between players or external events that affect several players), the number of players who leave is a Binomial random variable $X$ with parameters $t$ and $p_0$.  The probability that $X > t-m+1$ is then indeed given by your formula.

If you want a "simplified" formula without the sum, it can be expressed using 
a hypergeometric function:
$$ {t\choose t-m+2} {\frac { \left( 1-p_{{0}} \right) ^{-2+m}}{{p_{{0}}}^{
-2-t+m}}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(1,-m+2;\,t-m+3;\,{\frac {p_{{0}}}{p_{{0}}-1}})}}
$$

but this is probably not going to be much help to you.  There are also approximations (normal and Poisson) that can be used if $t$ is large.